# daskdataframe.to_parquet(): ChunkedEncodingError"

Tags: python, bigdata, dask

I have a huge dask dataframe with 100 partitions, reading 100 json file from gcs:

```
 dd = dd.read_json('gs://dask_xxxxx/2018-04-18/data-*.json')
```

then I use `to_parquet("x.parq")`:

```
  dd.to_parquet('x.parq')
```

I got the below error:

> ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: OSError("(54, \'ECONNRESET\')",)', OSError("(54, 'ECONNRESET')",))

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help unfortunately.  I recommend trying to produce an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MRocklin my code has 2 lines only: dd = dd.read_json('gs://dask_xxxxx/2018-04-18/data-*.json') and dd.to_parquet('x.parq')

Comment: That lacks the CV in MCVE

Comment: @MRocklin how can I do it without sharing my data? does head(dd) useful?